# Make all activities full screen - no title bar no activity bar

Tags: android, xml

I need to remove action bar/ title bar from all activities I am using. Currently I applied

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

in Manifest file under activity but this only removes above said from the main activity other activity remains the same. Any solution

Full code under activity :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.dss.ms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"            
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

Full Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dss.ms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
 >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dss.ms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"            
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.com.dss.ms.Single"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_single" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dss.ms.Index"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_index" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dss.ms.da"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_players_2" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dss.ms.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dss.ms.Score"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_score" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Final Edit ---

I got it worked, The problem arises when activity extends ActionBarActivity. I am attaching the reference. 
[[ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom][1])

In my final code I am using :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

under application in my Manifest file. Thank you.

Comment: hey, have you done with this or not still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set Theme or your application in application tag of your proiject's manifest file like:

```
<application 
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
</application>
```

Comment: paste your logcat so that we  analyse at what point  your app got crash.

Comment: It finally worked, updated in my final edit, Thankyou.

Comment: i think then you have to accept answer and upvote too.

Comment: @Dev  i applied in my app it works but as well as it change my tabbar colors as well how to resolve ?

Answer (score 7):

This code use in manifest file in :-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: This works for main activity but app crashes as soon as it moves to another activity

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your main activity inside onCreate

```
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    //Remove notification bar
     this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,      
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
     this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

add this to all pages

Answer (score 2):

Set this `Theme` to your `Application` Level like

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
 ....
 ...
 </application>
```

Comment: This works on main activity but app crashes as we move on to next activity

Comment: @user3521965 then post your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

to `application` tag instead of `activity`