# Google Play Services in Fullscreen?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Can I use the Google Play activities in full screen mode?

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);
builder.addApi(Games.API);
builder.addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES);
builder.addConnectionCallbacks(this);
builder.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this);
apiClient=builder.build();
apiClient.connect();
```

My app uses WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN but the activity that is shown by the api client shows the status bar at the top of the screen. Can I prevent this?

I tried the suggestions from

- [Make all activities full screen - no title bar no activity bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201380/make-all-activities-full-screen-no-title-bar-no-activity-bar)
- [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

but they didn't appear to have any effect.

[image: sample]

Comment: Did you try "http://stackoverflow.com/a/24201899/1484047" ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with Cordova but it's the same code: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/a14c7942557fbaea41438bd3fe104b47997d8371/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java#L304-L320

Answer (score 0):

Play services triggers an intent to their activities, makes sense to force the aspect of something as important as that not to be customizable by the user.
If you can do this, you should be able to completely change the theme, which might not be a serious problem in this example but showing something as important as buying stuff for example is critical to have exactly the same aspect across all the devices so the user can associate that dialog with Google Wallet (to name just an example).

As they are migrating all the important APIs to the google Play services bundle, they want to show the information in a consistent way and of course, for choosing an account for the Play Games is not critical the status bar but some of the services might need it to follow the process in the status bar (for example buying/downloading stuff) so the design must be consistent.

I'm not saying it cannot be done, I'd say it should not be safe to let you do it.

Comment: That's just speculation. Can you give a link to the docs on this topic?

Comment: Of course is just a speculation, what do you expect, the documentation where Google says "I don't want you to change the design of my activities" ?