# Error when using Robolectric to test an ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, robolectric, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I'm using Robolectric to test an activity from my application. The Activity extends ActionBarActivity. When I test the activity I get the error :

> IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

My testing environment is this:

- Android Studio 0.8.6
- Robolectric 2.4-SNAPSHOT
- support-v4 library version 20.0
- appcompat-v7 version 20.0

Now for the classes. The activity :

```
public class FilterActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

The test class:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class FilterActivityTest 
{
    private FilterActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {   
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FilterActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        activity.finish();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnCreate()
    {

    }
}
```

My styles.xml from values folder:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
```

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
at ro.cursurideschimb.user.FilterActivity.onCreate(FilterActivity.java:97)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:113)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:265)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:110)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:120)
at ro.cursurideschimb.user.FilterActivityTest.setUp(FilterActivityTest.java:38)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:267)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:194)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does your `android:theme` property of the `application` element in your AndroidManifest point to?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I believe this is caused by using `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` vs `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Base.Theme.MyApp">
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/charcoal_gray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Also, possibly worth mentioning, is that when using the newer versions of the support library, it is recommended to switch `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` since the former is now deprecated.

If you are using an older target sdk, this may apply to you: [ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom)