# Android Custom ActionBar Style

Tags: android, xml, themes

I'm trying to make a custom theme for my android app. But the problem is that I can't change actionbar theme. When the style is applied, it gave me the following error and shutdown the app:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.liderlink.dev.acelink" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AcelinkTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Dashboard"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**res/values/themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="AcelinkTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AcelinkActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- colors -->
    <color name="aceblue">#438eb9</color>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="AcelinkActionBar"
        parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/aceblue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Your logcat clearly says that you need to use `Appcompact` theme for your app if you are using `appcompact -v7 library`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear : you need to use a theme that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat`, probably because you are using `ActionBarActivity`, which requires it as specified in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html).

You can do this :

```
<style name="AcelinkTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AcelinkActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="AcelinkActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/aceblue</item>
</style>
```

For clarity, it is better to have colors defined in their own resource file IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom), you should change your parent to a Theme.AppCompat theme derivate:

```
<style name="AcelinkTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AcelinkActionBar</item>
</style>
```

This link should also help you to customize your theme: [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) :)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for details

Comment: Oops, sorry, I will pay attention :)