# Android style app minSdkVersion="8" targetSdkVersion="21"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'm creating an app with minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="21"

In AndroidManifest I have:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in the file styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
```

in the file values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

in the file values-v14/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

The `Activity` extends to `ActionBarActivity`

When I run the app I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

What i need to do to have an app running well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom)

Comment: possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is because the `Activity` you are extending `ActionBarActivity` which requires the `AppCompat` theme to be applied.

Change the Java inheritance from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity`.