# "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme"

Tags: java, android, dialog, themes

I'm programming an application on android, and I've a little problem :
I would like to make a customiz Dialog box so I do like in the android documentation :

In my manifest :

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/indice"
        android:label="33"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity android:name=".Autres.Indice"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">

        </activity>
```

In style :

```html
<style name = "AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>
```

But when I run : 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I don't understand, thank's^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You are having this issue because the activity you are trying to apply the dialog theme to is not extending `Activity`, that requires `AppCompat` theme.

Change

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

For

```
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
```