# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. Change to Theme.AppCompat causes other error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I use appcompat v22.1.0 in my App and use Toolbar. Everything was fine when I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. When I start implement `AlertDialog`, it produce error like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:47)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:92)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:882)
        at com.ramabmtr.map.findingmoo.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:216)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2572)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:74)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:164)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:740)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:598)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16989)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Based on that error, I change my theme to `Theme.AppCompat` and put this:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to my theme. But it produce the same error.

**Style.xml (old)**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**Style.xml (new)**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Anyone knows how to fix it??

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.ramabmtr.map.findingmoo;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView toolbarTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/panpizza.ttf");
    toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbarTitle.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.filter_title);
    builder.setMessage("test");
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

Comment: `When I start implement AlertDialog` where i the code for alert dialog?

Comment: DO NOT use application context for inflating views, creating dialogs. `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` would be fine as well because it reads `alertDialogTheme` attribute.

Comment: Visit this link here for solving the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940291/4832664

Comment: In my case, I change import from (import androidx.app.AlertDialog)to (import android.app.AlertDialog) and error is resolved.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Basically your Activity is using Toolbar (which replaces Action Bar) so you need to use style for the Activity that has no Action Bar like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.
If you have your own style for dialog then you need to inherit the proper AppCompat theme.

```
<style name="myDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog));
```

Comment: But if I use `AlertDialog`, it give me error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` is for theming activities, `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert` is for theming alert dialogs. The former causes visible double window frame for alert dialogs on platforms prior to Lollipop.

Comment: in my case i replace the parent to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: Just pass the `MainActivity.this` to Builder will work fine.

Comment: This doesn't works from Fragment. Error: `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: I get this error `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: @Martin use ActivityName.this to Builder

Answer (score 120):

Fixed my problem by using MainActivity.this (or YourActivityName.this)

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Make sure you already Theme.AppCompat and extending AppCompatActivity.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. Excellent, thanks!

Comment: So many complicated answers to this question and this is the best one.  Very simple, no xml files to be changed.  One must presume that the person with this question already has working xml files.  This just extends the use of that existing code.

Comment: Simply using `getAplicationContext()` will not work. You have to use the format specified above.

Comment: @mariozawa Your answer worked for me. Thank you. +1!

Comment: In kotlin creating the dialog uses this@MainActivity, like so: val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).create()

Comment: In Kotlin: val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity()) is the only thing that works for me.

Comment: For Kotlin could also work: AlertDialog.Builder(this@YourActivity)

Answer (score 59):

In my case, this crash was caused because I was passing `View.getContext().getApplicationContext()` as `Context` to the `Builder`. This was fixed by using `getActivity()` instead.

Comment: I had to do `view.getContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. Thank you so much, your answer saved my bacon for my assignment due today.

Comment: Back again after 4 months. I passed in `this`/`mainActivity` to my `AlertBuilder`, but I'm using `viewBinding` so those values were invalid. I had to pass `binding.getRoot().getContext()` instead.

Answer (score 23):

Saw this same exception using `Activity` and `Theme.Light` theme. My problem was a wrong import, I was using the support one. `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;` instead of 
`import android.app.AlertDialog;`

Comment: Bingo bango bongo! This did it for me.

Comment: This was the fix that I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 12):

if you have this error when you creating a dialog (just in my case) **you should use the following**:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
```

instead of:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

This worked me perfectly!

Comment: This worked for me, but I changed `R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light` to `Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog` so that the dialog doesn't use the full screen.

Answer (score 5):

The probem is because of Context which You are passing to build the Alert Dialog.Don't Use getApplicationContext().Try using your Activity context.Use `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActiviy.this);`

Answer (score 5):

This work for me... after read several answer was...

Change my import like this:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

instead of

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

this give error Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application... so I change the context of the builder from

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
```

AlertDialog.Builder(getAplicationContext()); 
to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(*MainActivity.this*);
```

Comment: Please explain bit more

Comment: I had the same mistake as him. My app crashed only when displaying an AlertDialog. I mistakenly imported an AppCompat version

Answer (score 4):

Adding Android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" like this in manifest

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

Just put your activity here:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(your_activity.this);
```

instead of

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using support library your activity extends `AppCompactActivity`, if you use `android studio` to create activity this is default. In such case pass context to the builder as `ActivityName.this` or simply `this` if you are passing it in `onCreate`, passing `getApplicationContext()` will not work.

This is my style using `appcompact`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And everything is working fine when I use `this` or `ActivityName.this` as mentioned above (here ActivityName is the name of your current activity i.e. `MainActivity.this`).

If you are using in fragment you should pass `getActivity()` as context to builder instead of `getContext()`.

Comment: appcompact style  :)

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin this worked to me:

```
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your Activity's context instead to pass your Context. Try with "this" instead "context". This work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to check and make sure that all styles.xml files use `Theme.AppCompat`. The standard styles.xml file had that theme but there were also styles(v21).xml, styles(v11).xml and styles(sw600dp).xml that were auto-generated. The simple solution would be to copy and paste the customized default AppTheme style into these folders.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful with such problem, i've waisted long long hours on such bug.
it happens only on android 4.4.2 version, despite the fact that i'm using the Appcompat theme everywhere, tried to play with all styles and use many other threads and answers.

the problem was caused by this line:

```
 <style name="LooperLabTheme"
        parent.theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<style/>
```

please notice the "parent.theme", i've copied it from some answer in the first days of launching the project that i'm woking on, it should be "parent" without the theme.

```
 <style name="LooperLabTheme"
            parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <style/>
```

I just want to help others who are running from thread to thread to find out the fix for his very specific problem, it might be the same as mine, save your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()

AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
} else {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
}
builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog")
       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        })
       .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
       .show();
```