# AlertDialog error: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, listadapter

I got this issue and dont know how to fix it. here my manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```

here my onclick in listAdapter

```
holder.iconDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //need to confirm it first
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Delete Setcard")
                    .setMessage("Do you really want to delete setcard?")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //run API volley
                            deleteSetcard(setcard_id);
                        }})
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
        }
    });
```

I tried other solution like changing the theme using Theme.AppCompat.Light

but none working

Comment: post the full error stack trace and your `styles.xml`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. Change to Theme.AppCompat causes other error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180052/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity-chan)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. Change to Theme.AppCompat causes other error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180052/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity-chan)

Answer (score 4):

I hope this one is help to you

```
 <style name="myDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    ...
 </style>
```

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog));
```

Answer (score 1):

I face such a case and I was managed to solve it. Here it is:

- define your Alert Dialog in MainActivity class, example:

  ```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
  ```
- then initialize it on OnCreate() method just like below:

  ```
  alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  ```
- then you can do the rest of alert Dialog customization like icon, title, message anywhere you like. in my case i used it in onFinish() of count down timer as shown below:

  ```
  public void onFinish() {

              alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame);
              alertDialog.setTitle("You are done");
              alertDialog.setMessage("you got it");
              alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                      runTheCode();
                  }
              });
              alertDialog.show();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

When using an AppCompat theme, you must ensure that your Activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, and that you import `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` from the Android Support Library instead of  `android.app.AlertDialog`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <style name="InvitationDialog" 
     parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Code

```
       new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.InvitationDialog)
       .setTitle("Delete Setcard")
                .setMessage("Do you really want to delete setcard?")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
                   whichButton) {
                        //run API volley
                        deleteSetcard(setcard_id);
                    }})
                .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
                }
});
```