# Why won't my Android App open in Fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-fullscreen

I know that this question has been asked before, but the provided answers did not solve my case, so I'll ask for an individual solution.

## My code

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".KategorieAuswahl"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kategorie_auswahl" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ZeigeFragen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_zeige_fragen" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

And my styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want my App to open in fullscreen and to hide the TitleBar. The first thing I did was to add a `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` attribute to the `<application>`-Tag of my AndroidManifest.xml.

This leads to the error *You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.* Here is the full stacktrace:

```
05-27 21:24:26.889    2121-2121/de.test.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.test.myapp/de.test.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at de.test.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There are [multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity) on stackoverflow referencing this error.

---

## Approach #1

[One solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/586085) suggests to change the Java inheritance from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and leave the manifest as it is.

So I updated my the `<style>` element in my styles.xml and removed the DarkActionBar part:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

This still gives me the same error.

---

## Approach #2

[The next solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27269642/586085) suggests to change my styles.xml's parent attribute from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">`

This makes it possible to use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` for my `<activity>`, but I don't see an option to make it fullscreen then.

---

## Approach #3

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23017863/586085) soggests to add `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` to my `<style>` element but this doesn't change anything at all.

---

## Conclusion

I really tried a lot, but nothing seems to work. Anyway I have problems understanding the theme inheritance chain and when I may use .NoTitleBar and .Fullscreen.

After all I don't care which theme to use, as long I can make the app fullscreen without a title bar. Can you help me to pick the right attributes?

Answer (score 0):

extend `ActionBarActivity` or the new one, and use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, now in your `Activity`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    Activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}else{
    Activity.getWindow().getDecorView().
            setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);              
}
```

Hope it helps..