# button to show an image android app

Tags: android

I would like to make a simple app with a button that shows a picture when pressed.
Here is what I've written.

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="Activityfullscreen"></activity>
</application>
```

main:

```
package com.mycompany.button_show;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent inf=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activityfullscreen.class);

                startActivity(inf);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

.java for the second activity:

    public class Activityfullscreen  extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.widget45);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aa);
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget45"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity full screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget45"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

styles:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

When I run, everything is fine, but when I launch the app I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Style.xml`, you need to use `AppCompat` Theme - (**RECOMMENDED**)

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

The above theme is Material Light theme.

Otherwise, you can leave `AppCompat`(But I don't recommend this as AppCompat is used for Material themes for lower Android versions like Jellybean, Honeycomb and Gingerbread) by using this code in Main - (**NOT RECOMMENDED**)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { // Changed from AppCompatActivity to just Activity

    ... Enter the code you use here

}
```

Change this too if you use the `NOT RECOMMENDED` method -

```
public class Activityfullscreen  extends Activity { // Changed from AppCompatActivity to just Activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.widget45);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aa);
}
```

If you like this answer, please mark it as `selected`.
**PS -** `Material.light` is available only on Android 4.4 (Kitkat) +

Comment: If I change Material into AppCompat, I get that such as symbol is not resolved. Should I install something?

Comment: Actually, I have solved with this:       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">. Also I replaced "public class Activityfullscreen  extends AppCompatActivity" with"public class Activityfullscreen  extends Activity". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ohh, that meant you didn't have the latest AppCompat library. Anways, nice that you solved your problem.