# my activity extends AppCompatActivity and crash on Launch

Tags: android, android-theme, appcompatactivity

I am creating one application and i am getting error,

On launching it crash and says

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Here is my Activity:

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Here is my manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is complete error log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-16 15:56:26.135
>   25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse E/AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.social_infotech.renthouse/com.social_infotech.renthouse.activity.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity. 10-16 15:56:26.135
>   25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 10-16
>   15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-16 15:56:26.135
>   25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-16 15:56:26.135
>   25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 10-16
>   15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-16 15:56:26.135
>   25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-16
>   15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You
>   need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity. 10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:112)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:148)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:60)
>   10-16 15:56:26.135 25342-25342/com.social_infotech.renthouse
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.social_infotech.renthouse.activity.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:16)

Comment: Check your manifest and make sure your activity uses `@style/AppTheme` or `@style/AppBaseTheme`.

Comment: my manifest uses android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: Have u included appCompat support library as Library

Comment: Post the manifest and the complete error message. Something's not adding up :)

Comment: In the dependencies  i have added compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

Comment: what is your targeted version of app? @piyushporiya

Comment: my  targetSdkVersion 23..@Andrain

Comment: @piyush :Give Daniels answer a try it might work , remove appcompatactivity and add Activity

Comment: yes i have tried but same error..

Comment: You didn't post your manifest.

Comment: please see edit question @Simas

Comment: hey u mentioned as AppTheme1,change it to Apptheme in manifest

Comment: yes i have edited app Them so some reason..but i have double check i am using same them

Comment: no still there is same error..Not able to do anything..

Comment: Post the **complete** files: activity, manifest, styles. And please copy and paste - you won't have to "double-check".

Comment: i have posted everything.

Comment: Did you solve this? Please post a solution if you have

Answer (score 0):

Extends your activity with FragmentActivity or Activity
Because you are using NoAcionBar as your theme.

Answer (score 0):

for a noActionBar activity :

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
   android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
   android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class SplashscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've said, something's not adding up.

You seem to be using different themes:

In the manifest you have

```
@style/AppTheme1
```

while the styles file contains

```
@style/AppTheme
```

Comment: yes i have posted manifest file first and for some reason i have checked in both i am using same style

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your following code to your **values-21** *>>>* **Styles.xml** 
then clean your project and try to run.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>

</style>
  <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom).

**EDIT**: A few answer from the above thread may help you with this issue. I'll list a summary:

1. [molokoka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20193844/3812244)'s answer, in order to *add ActionBarCompat in your activity or application should use @style/Theme.AppCompat theme in AndroidManifest.xml like this*:

`<activity
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />`

molokoka also states that usually you need to customize your ActionBar. Once again, please follow his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20193844/3812244) for details.

2. [tyczj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689563/3812244) also makes a very good point:
   *Check and make sure that you do not have another values folder that references theme.styled and does not use AppCompat theme*

ie `values-v11` folder.

**Side note: Sorry, I'm unable to add a comment due to low reputation. That's the reason why I placed an answer.**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Anirudh Sharma, apologies. I hope the edit can help not only the OP, but anyone who may need it.