# How can I fix this error: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog, appcompatactivity

I searched all internet web sites to fix this error, but I couldn't. I just want to create AlertDialog with two button Yes and No.

This is my code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

    Button btnDialog= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
    btnDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialogMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void showDialogMessage(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    // Add the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

And this is my Style:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

this is my style(v21):

```
<resources>
<!-- extend one of the Theme.AppCompat themes -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorHighLight</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

this is manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.saly.rastari" >   
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I click on Dialog button I get this error:

```
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.irannara.pda.pdaassistant, PID: 24352
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:76)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:216)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.irannara.pda.pdaassistant.DialogActivity.showDialogMessage(DialogActivity.java:42)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.irannara.pda.pdaassistant.DialogActivity.access$000(DialogActivity.java:10)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.irannara.pda.pdaassistant.DialogActivity$1.onClick(DialogActivity.java:21)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-02 04:36:55.941 24352-24352/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
11-02 04:36:55.959 718-718/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 718: eglCreateSyncKHR(1209): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

none of this links couldn't help me:

- [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)
- [ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom)
- [Need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity???](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/need-to-use-a-themeappcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

and more.

how can i fix this?

Comment: show us your manifest to help you

Comment: Did you try using support AlertDialog?

Comment: yes import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have another styles files in side another values folders like "`values-v11`", "`values-v14`"... Edit theme also and try to clean your app before running.

Edited:
From your activity change `getApplicationContext()` to `this`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Because the dialog also should extends the `Appcompat` Theme.

Comment: thank you so much @John, my problem solved, its because `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Happy to hear that. So, consider to mark this as `accepted answer` for other people who has the same problem can solve it quickly.

Comment: `getApplicationContext()`  was problem , fixed by replacing to `this` thanks @NamNH

Answer (score 1):

If anybody experiences this issue with activities, try to explicitly configure a theme to your activity.

```
<activity android:name=".activities.BLEControlActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering this error because your `AlertDialog` is not using AppCompat theme while your activity is. To fix it, use the `this` property of your activity instead of `getApplicationContext()`, like so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
```

The name of your activity, followed by `.this`, in this case `DialogActivity.this`, should always be used instead of only `this`, because if your dialog is created inside another class, for example an adapter of some sort, you will receive a compile-time error stating that a `Context` was expected instead of the adapter class given.

Answer (score 0):

in your style.xml file add below code-

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" 
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

also define theme like this in your activity

```
 <activity
            android:name=".DialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme.Dialog">
```

OR

```
<activity
            android:name=".DialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

clean project and run again..

Answer (score 0):

I face such a case and I was managed to solve it. Here it is:

- define your Alert Dialog in MainActivity class, example:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
```

- then initialize it on OnCreate() method just like below:

```html
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

- then you can do the rest of alert Dialog customization like icon, title, message anywhere you like. in my case i used it in onFinish() of count down timer as shown below:

```html
public void onFinish() {

                alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame);
                alertDialog.setTitle("You are done");
                alertDialog.setMessage("you got it");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        runTheCode();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

to me i go to themes.xml file in values folder and update

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

with

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding following to your proguard-rules:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

If you are using

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0

Have a look at Google Issue [190237](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190237)